# How to avoid boxing of value types

Tags: c#, generics, boxing

Suppose I have some class that invokes a `Func` based upon the generic type passed to it, and I have a desired public interface for that class something like this:

```
var r = new Resolver(); 
var i = r.Invoke(10); // invokes some function `Func<int,int>`
var j = r.Invoke("Hello"); // Same, but `Func<string,string>`
var k = r.Invoke(10, 10); // Same but 'Func<int,int,int>`
```

I have an implementation like this:

```
class Resolver {
    readonly IDictionary<Type, Func<object, object>> _funcs = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>();

    public Resolver() {
        _funcs.Add(typeof(int), o => (int)o*(int)o);
        _funcs.Add(typeof(string), o => (string)o + (string)o);
        // and so on; 
    }

    public T Invoke<T>(T t1) {
        return (T) _funcs[typeof (T)](t1);
    }

    public T Invoke<T>(T t1, T t2) {
        return (T)_funcs[typeof(T)](t1);
    }
}
```

but performance is horrible for value types because of the boxing caused by the internal implementation of the `Func<,>` having `object` as generic types.

Is there a way to implement my desired public interface avoiding boxing for value types? I also wouldn't mind static type safety inside the implementation, but could live without.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do the following simple trick (not any more or less type safe than your current implementation):

```
class Resolver
{
    readonly IDictionary<Type, object> _unaryFuncs = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    readonly IDictionary<Type, object> _binaryFuncs = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public Resolver()
    {
        _unaryFuncs.Add(typeof(int),  new Func<int, int>(o => o * o));
        _unaryFuncs.Add(typeof(string), new Func<string, string(o => o + o));
        _binaryFuncs.Add(typeof(int), new Func<int, int, int>((x, y) => x + y));
        // and so on; 
    }

    public T Invoke<T>(T t1)
    {
        var f = _unaryFuncs[typeof(T)] as Func<T, T>;
        return f(t1);
    }

    public T Invoke<T>(T t1, T t2)
    {
        var f = _binaryFuncs[typeof(T)] as Func<T, T, T>;
        return f(t1, t2);
    }
}
```

You may want to add some error checking like checking that

1. a `T` function is registered, before getting it from the dictionary.
2. it is not `null` after the `as` cast.

And add typesafe registration functions:

```
public void Register<T>(Func<T, T> unaryFunc)
{
    _unaryFuncs[typeof(T)] = unaryFunc;
}

public void Register<T>(Func<T, T, T> binaryFunc)
{
    _binaryFuncs[typeof(T)] = binaryFunc;
}
```

Comment: This is a great way to avoid my assumed problem. However, it's clear based upon my own testing that boxing isn't the main cause of the performance problem I am experiencing. Nonetheless, I appreciate the response. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a static generic variable to cache your resolver.  In my quick testing, this took about a third of the time to execute and avoids boxing.

Since `ResolverCache<Func<int,int>>.Resolver` is a different variable than `ResolverCache<Func<string,string>>.Resolver`, you can store the different resolvers in a type-safe way.

```
class Resolver
{
    static class ResolverCache<T>
    {
        public static T Resolver { get; set; }
    }

    void AddResolver<T>(T resolver)
    {
        ResolverCache<T>.Resolver = resolver;
    }

    public Resolver()
    {
        Func<int, int> intResolver = o => (int)o * (int)o;
        Func<int, int, int> intResolver2 = (o, p) => (int)o * (int)p;
        Func<string, string> stringResolver = o => (string)o + (string)o;

        AddResolver(intResolver);
        AddResolver(intResolver2);
        AddResolver(stringResolver);

        // and so on; 
    }

    public T Invoke<T>(T t1)
    {
        var resolver = ResolverCache<Func<T, T>>.Resolver ?? (v => { throw new Exception("No resolver registered."); });
        return resolver(t1);
    }

    public T Invoke<T>(T t1, T t2)
    {
        var resolver = ResolverCache<Func<T, T, T>>.Resolver ?? ((v, u) => { throw new Exception("No resolver registered."); });
        return resolver(t1, t2);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Perfect. I was looking for a way to pass through generics without incurring boxing, and this gave me exactly the push I needed to solve the problem. Thank you!